# How to set DesiredSize.Width of a UIElement?

Tags: wpf, size, width, uielement, measureoverride

I need to calculate the `Width` of each `UIElement` in a custom panel.  If looping over `Children`:

```
foreach (UIElement child in Children) { ... }
```

I can't do `child.DesiredSize.Width = myCalculatedWidth;` since `DesiredSize` and `DesiredSize.Width` are read only.

The docs say that that `Measure()` updates the `DesiredSize` of the `UIElement`, so I tried:

```
Size size = new Size(myCalculatedWidth, Double.PositiveInfinity);
child.Measure(size);
```

But `child.DesiredSize.Width` is unchanged.  How do I set the `DesiredSize.Width`?

Answer (score 3):

If you call `Measure` directly there are nothing to do for WPF layout system (because it caches the state of controls and store it as flags like `MeasureIsValid`). You should call `InvalidateMeasure()` for this control (which will mark control as `MeasureIsValid = false)` and `UpdateLayout()` then to force layout to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Just try with `child.Width = myCalculatedWidth`.

Comment: `UIElement` doesn't have a `Width` property.

Answer (score 1):

Call `InvalidateArrange()`. The rendering system will call `Arrange(Rect)` and update the `DesiredSize` of the UIElement with your size.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers worked for me.  What I needed to do was to implement `MeasureOverride` in the child control and implement the desired layout behavior there.

Answer (score 1):

One cannot change directly DesiredSize, since only UIElement can write to DesiredSize, which happens in
UIElement.Measure(). However, Measure() does not calculate DesiredWidth, but calls MeasurementCore instead. But even MeasurementCore does not calculate DesiredSize directly, but uses the return value of MeasurementOverride instead. That's the reason you have to override MeasurementOverride() to change DesiredChange :-)

It looks like this:

```
UIElement.Measure() calls 
  FrameworkElement.MeasureCore() calls
    YourControl.MeasureOverwrite()
```

return value of MeasureOverwrite() becomes return value of MeasureCore(), which then is stored in UIElement.DesiredSize.

Note that the value returned by MeasureOverwrite() is not necessarily the same as stored in DesiredSize, because the Margin gets added to the returned value ! FrameworkElement.MeasurementCore() also ensures that DesiredSize is within MinWidth, MaxWidth and Height, respectively. If the Width or Height of the returned value isInfinite of isNaN, an exception gets thrown.